# Intermediate context does not exist: jms/searchaccount

Tags: java, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty

i am getting below error while connecting to MQ from liberty server

```
NamingException JMSMessageHandler class : Intermediate context does not exist: jms/searchaccount
[12/2/21 16:41:41:671 IST] 00000045 SystemErr                                                    R javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Intermediate context does not exist: jms/searchaccount
[12/2/21 16:41:41:672 IST] 00000045 SystemErr                                                    R      at com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.ContextNode.getTargetNode(ContextNode.java:125)
[12/2/21 16:41:41:673 IST] 00000045 SystemErr                                                    R      at com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.ContextNode.lookup(ContextNode.java:211)
[12/2/21 16:41:41:673 IST] 00000045 SystemErr                                                    R      at com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WSContext.lookup(WSContext.java:304)
```

server.xml

```
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
        <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
        <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
        <feature>osgiConsole-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jca-1.7</feature>
        <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
        <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
        <feature>mdb-3.2</feature>
        <!-- <feature>usr:prometheusExporter-1.0</feature> -->
        <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
        <feature>restConnector-2.0</feature>
        <feature>monitor-1.0</feature>
        <feature>springBoot-2.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.2</feature>
        <feature>mpMetrics-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jmsMdb-3.2</feature>
        <feature>wmqJmsClient-2.0</feature>


  <variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location" value="${env.SSLCRTS}/wmq.jmsra.rar"/>
    <jmsConnectionFactory id="searchmqcf" jndiName="jms/searchaccount">
                <properties.wmqJms channel="QMDOXGWS.TMS.SVRCO" hostName="10.94.135.146" port="7226" queueManager="QMDOXGWS" sslCipherSuite="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" transportType="CLIENT"/>
        </jmsConnectionFactory>                
        <jmsQueue id="searchReq" jndiName="jms/searchaccountreq">
                <properties.wmqJms baseQueueName="DOX.SV.SEARCHSRV.ESB.RQI.01" targetClient="MQ"/>
        </jmsQueue>
        <jmsQueue id="searchResp" jndiName="jms/searchaccountres">
                <properties.wmqJms baseQueueName="DOX.SV.TMS.SEARCHSRV.ESB.RPO.01" targetClient="MQ"/>
        </jmsQueue>
```

Comment: You need to add `server.xml` part which configures wmq resources and part of code that is using it, as now it is not possible to say anything about the error.

Comment: thank you for your reponse. i have added details in question

Comment: No, you didnt add anything useful. Put whole server.xml if you dont know which part contains jndi mq configuration.

Comment: i have added more details .. hope this sufficient.. please help me

Comment: Add your Java code, or Spring code that uses that JNDI name. You also have conflicting features. You should know if your app is springboot or webprofile.... Are you using WebSphere Liberty or OpenLiberty, which version?